# React Native AAR Libraries

Tags: android, react-native

Every time I add react native library it add an android project

So I wonder why React native libraries are an android projects not aar files 
why the react native's Android libraries are not just js files and 1 aar?

Comment: did you find out? its confusing me, also causing some issues when migrating to AndroidX

Comment: I did not find a solution as there is no answers